# DataReader returns wrong values

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

Hi I am really confused Let me explain firstly .I am trying to retrieve data from northwind .
In the orders table first column is OrderID and the second column is CustomerID

> Console.Write(reader[0].ToString());

using like this I can get the values 1248,1249,1250 and so on) as it is expected .But if i use this way like below .

```
                Console.Write(reader[0].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ----------------");
                Console.WriteLine(reader[1].ToString());
```

Data comes from Orders are completely different this time.if you check orders table you will see that this data is not belong OrdersTable.Could you please  help?

```
           10779    Mork
           10780    Lilas
```

this is the complete code

```
        string SQL = "SELECT * FROM Orders";

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL);
        cmd.Connection = conn;

        conn.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
               // Console.Write( reader.GetString(1).ToString());

                Console.Write(reader[0].ToString());
                Console.Write(" ----------------");
                Console.WriteLine(reader[1].ToString());

             //  Console.WriteLine("Customer:" + reader.GetString(1).ToString());

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        finally
        {
            reader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Please show how you obtained your reader.

Comment: Why not just use reader["ColumnName] ?

Comment: On another note: you should make use of using blocks for resources like SqlConnection, see examples.

Comment: Just debug and see what columns the reader provide. It is definitely a bad choice to use reader[1] instead of reader["columnname"]

Comment: I'll strongly suggest you to use reader["ColumnName]. this way it will work even when Columns are rearranged.

Answer (score 0):

```
Console.Write(reader.GetString(0));
Console.Write(" ----------------");
Console.WriteLine(reader.GetString(1));
```

or `reader.GetInt32(n)`, depends what the types are?

assuming you're after the first two columns of each row?

**EDIT**: I think I initially read the question wrong, you're saying that when you query Orders table from [this schema](http://www.daltinkurt.com/upload/2012/12/NorthwindLayout.JPG), you're getting a name in ordinal position 1, i.e. the second column?

based on this schema, I searched for vinet and saw this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfb76340-6770-4146-8576-eca7bbcc94a3/not-getting-systemdatalinqentitiyset-meta-data) and you can see the poster is querying `customerId == 'VINET'`, so I suspect the result you are seeing is correct. Try running:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = 'VINET'
```

Comment: Unfortunately Same result diffrent from Orders table

Comment: I have tried same code for the diffrent table("Products") everything is  ok.I am so confused.What is wrong